# how to specify disk size in openstack create instance

Tags: cloud, openstack, jclouds

I'm using the below code in openstack for create instance which will use openstack flavor list to get the hardware details. Is there any was to pass the disk size explicitly using computeService API ?

```
ComputeServiceContext computeContext = ContextBuilder.newBuilder(credentials.getProviderName()) 
            .endpoint(credentials.getResourceEndPoint()) 
            .credentials(cred, passwd)
            .modules(ImmutableSet.<Module> of(new SshjSshClientModule())) 
            .overrides(openStackPropeties)
            .buildView(ComputeServiceContext.class);

templateBuilder.imageId(instance.getImageId());
            templateBuilder.hardwareId(instance.getInstanceType());
            options.as(NovaTemplateOptions.class).nodeNames(
                    new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(instance
                            .getInstanceName())));
            options.as(NovaTemplateOptions.class).networks(
                    instance.getNetworkType());
            templateBuilder.locationId("RegionOne"); 
            build = templateBuilder.build();

Set<? extends NodeMetadata> nodeMetadatas = computeService.createNodesInGroup("securitygroup.name",
                    instanceCount, build);
```

Answer (score 0):

TemplateBuilder has a minDisk(double gigabytes) option that can be used to supply minimum disk size.

https://jclouds.apache.org/reference/javadoc/1.9.x/org/jclouds/compute/domain/TemplateBuilder.html#minDisk(double)

Comment: Do you have nova flavors that match that minDisk size? I believe if should filter the list of flavors using that variable. One thing that could help determine what is going on is enabling wire-level logging (as per https://jclouds.apache.org/reference/logging/) and seeing the list of nova flavors as well as which flavor is selected in the create call.